# Rails app is successfully deploying to Heroku but getting an application error when you visit the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Seeking insight into an issue I'm having with my current rails app. I am able to deploy the app to Heroku but am getting the following four warnings below from the heroku push. Once I navigate to the URL, it provides an application error page and the app is not showing. Any solutions to the warnings below are greatly appreciated!

WARNING:

```
   Removing `vendor/bundle`.
   Checking in `vendor/bundle` is not supported. Please remove this directory
   and add it to your .gitignore. To vendor your gems with Bundler, use
   `bundle pack` instead.
```

WARNING:

```
   You have the `.bundle/config` file checked into your repository
    It contains local state like the location of the installed bundle
    as well as configured git local gems, and other settings that should
   not be shared between multiple checkouts of a single repo. Please
   remove the `.bundle/` folder from your repo and add it to your `.gitignore` file.
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration
```

WARNING:

```
   Detecting rails configuration failed
   set HEROKU_DEBUG_RAILS_RUNNER=1 to debug
```

WARNING:

```
   We detected that some binary dependencies required to
   use all the preview features of Active Storage are not
   present on this system.
```

Comment: Have you tried to check Heroku logs?

Comment: I'd start with removing `vendor/bundle` and `.bundle` from your git repository.

Comment: The first two warnings are probably unrelated.  They can occur in some cases when .bundle/ and vendor/ are not checked in at all (not sure what triggers this), but the site can still work fine.